# How can I determine which revision and url was used to create a tag in Subversion?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

With Tortoise-SVN when you create a branch or a tag you specify the URL and revision to use as its source.  Can you later easily retrieve this information?

In my case I have been creating tags that include the full contents of `/trunk` or their source `branch`, but I would prefer to switch to only tagging the binaries produced by those versions.  If I do this I need to easily be able to retrieve the full source of the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it's quite simple.

Open the SVN Log on the tag itself, select "Stop on copy/rename", and it will be displayed under the first (only) revision of the tag.

[image]